# What are the objects in the following list?

Tags: class, object

Analyze the scenario for a retail store and identify minimum three different objects from the following

```
customer_name,

customer,

item_id,

description,

bill_amount,

price_per_unit,

item,

pays_bill,

purchases,

employee,

designation
```

I have tried `item_id`, `bill_amount` and `designation` as they are unique but the answer was wrong.

I also tried a lot of different options for quite a lot of time but did not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

The objects are instances of a class for example `employee`, `customer`, `item` and `purchase`. In the case of `customer`, you may have a class name `Customer` which has it's specified attributes such as `customer_name`, ``customer_id` etc.

And when you are ready to create a new customer, you will create an object name `customer` or `customer1` which would be instances of the class `Customer`.

Comment: Thanks but it did not answer my question that what are the 3 objects in the given list. I know what objects are but am not able to identify in the list

Comment: @New_Learner2121 That was the first thing I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

objects are employee, customer, item and purchase.

> customer

customer_name,
customer,

> item

item_id,
description,
price_per_unit,
item,

> purchase

pays_bill,
purchases,
bill_amount,

> employee

employee,
designation

Main objects are employee, customer, item and "purchase" contains new fields with the combination of first 3 objects

Comment: yes that's the correct answer. I figured it out even before you answered but still it means a lot. Thanks

Comment: Welcome...all the best for your future... (Y)

Comment: Can you mark this answer as correct? It will also help others to identify the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is Customer, Item, Employee

Comment: Since you are formally posting an answer to an older question. It would be most helpful that you support your purported answer with some code and the output that results from using your code